# What will this query return? (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, sql-like

The query is

```
SELECT userid, username
FROM Users
WHERE username LIKE '%Smith'
ORDER BY 3
```

It seems to me column 3 doesn't exist in the resultant query table

[image: Table here]

Comment: Probably an error.

Comment: This "syntax" shouldn't be used and (IMHO) should never be part of SQL standard. Note that `ORDER BY 1+2` is something different.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `ORDER BY 3` but you dont have 3 columns so (the third column doesn't exist). So it result in an error.

Without the `ORDER BY` clause, it will the return the first row.

Comment: *Without the ORDER BY clause, it will the return the first row.*: what do you mean by that?